# Using a value from a ComboBox of Enums for a parameter for a setter

Tags: java, combobox, enums

I'm sure theres a way to do this, but can't quite seem to get it.

I'm working on a program which has a combobox that is populated with enums.
I need to take the value selected and pass it to a setter method which currently takes a string as a parameter.

I think it'd work something like; user selects the enum value, program figures out what the value of that enum is in the enum list, then if possible just call a toString and pass it into the setter.

I'm probably way off, but any help is appreciated!

I've tried `String system = (String) play.getSelectedItem(); gGame.setPlayer(system);`
as well as `String system = play.getSelectedItem().toString():`

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried the following: 

`String system = (String) play.getSelectedItem();
gGame.setPlayer(system);` 

with play being the combobox.

Comment: you should post this in your question, but you don't have to cast, try `play.getSelectedItem().toString()`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i was actually about to post that I had tried it without the cast with no luck.

Comment: Post the code snippet where the values are assigned to `play` ComboBox

Comment: Or, post the `enum` definition that is being used to populate the combo box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sample of how an `enum` can be used in `JComboBox`

```
//Definition of the enum
enum ItemType {
  First("First choice"), Second("Second choice"), Third("Final choice");
  private final String display;
  private ItemType(String s) {
    display = s;
  }
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return display;
  }
}


//Assigning values of enum to 'play' JComboBox
play.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(ItemType.values()));

//Reading the value of JComboBox
ItemType selectedType = (ItemType)play.getSelectedItem();
gGame.setPlayer(selectedType); //toString is overridden, so it will assign the appropriate text value of the enum
```